# UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter not properly centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I have a view in which I want to draw a circle with `UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter`. My view's `initWithFrame` is as follows:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
    self.circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor.CGColor;
    self.circleLayer.lineWidth = 4;
    self.circleLayer.bounds = self.bounds;


    self.startAngle = 0.0;
    self.endAngle = M_PI *  2;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5, self.frame.size.height * 0.5);
    CGFloat radius = self.frame.size.height * 0.45;
    self.circleLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:self.startAngle endAngle:self.endAngle clockwise:YES].CGPath;

    [self.layer addSublayer:self.circleLayer];

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;

    return self;
}
```

I expected that would produce a black circle centered in my view. However, the actual output looks like this:
[image: Actual output]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The weirdest part is that it's drawn correctly after a fresh install of the app - any consecutive launches result in it being drawn like in the image attached. Why?

Comment: Try to use this code in drawRect method

Comment: `self.circleLayer.frame = self.bounds;`?

Comment: @Larme well, it is a sub-layer, so it needs to have `(0, 0)` origin. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MikeAlter I can't use in in `drawRect` because later I want to animate it in `CABasicAnimation`. Why does it display incorrectly as it is? I'm adding the `UIBezierPath` to `CAShapeLayer` for the purpose of not having to use it in `drawRect`

Comment: You're using "self.frame.size.width" to define the center of your circle. Try logging this. You can't be sure of it's size at this point. Your view could be initialized with (0,0) and then resized for all we know.

Comment: Try to set circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

Comment: @Kujey That's accounted for, I'm updating the path in `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 7):

Do not use view's center!

In my case, using ,

`let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)`

for center point solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this seems to be a bug in iOS. The `CAShapeLayer` has its bounds set properly

```
self.circleLayer.bounds = self.bounds;
```

Upon inspecting it, the origin and size of the layer is fine, but **only after first launch of the app after installing**. Any subsequent launch of the app will result in its size being `(0, 0)`. Removing the app and installing it again will result in the circle being drawn properly **once**.

I fixed it by setting the layer's frame again further down the road.

Comment: Did you try setting up the frame of your circle layer inside of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into somewhat same problem, but for me the path was not drawing in center of my view even on the first launch.

This was my code at the time of problem:
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: containerView.frame.size.width/2, y: containerView.frame.size.height/2), radius: 50, startAngle: (-CGFloat.pi / 2), endAngle: (CGFloat.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

the 'containerView' is the view containing the circle drawn by bazierpath.

but then I did the following on a hunch and it worked.

let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: containerView.frame.size.width/2, y: containerView.frame.size.height/2)

let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: 50, startAngle: (-CGFloat.pi / 2), endAngle: (CGFloat.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

Basically I had to create the center point before assigning it to the bazierpath. Hope this helps someone.